# Android: Custom NDK/C++ android.media.Image implementation backed by OpenGL texture/HardwareBuffer

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-image

I'm working on a Camera2 app where I have a custom OpenGL pipeline set up for processing video frames.

In my pipeline, I use a couple of different third party frame-processing APIs that expect an `android.media.Image` as parameter (e.g. for detecting faces, or other models).

I have a **OpenGL texture** which I can use to create & fill a **AHardwareBuffer**. How do I now **synchronously** create `android.media.Image` instances which are backed by my OpenGL Texture/HardwareBuffer?

1. I understand that the `android.media.Image` class' implementation is pretty much entirely in NDK/C++, but `AImage` from `mediandk` also doesn't provide a constructor.
2. I say **synchronously**, because I am aware of creating an `ImageReader` and then streaming into it's Surface, but this is not what I want since those are not synchronously created, but instead only created in the `setOnImageAvailableListener` callback.

Answer (score 0):

While an Android `media.Image` in fact is mostly a wrapper around a graphics buffer, and therefore at the low level can be treated as a AHardwareBuffer (plus metadata), there's unfortunately no public API to create a media.Image from  a AHardwareBuffer (though the other way around is possible) since the `media.Image` also has ownership semantics related to ImageReaders and Writers.

I know you'd like a synchronous solution, but I don't believe there is one, in the public API.  You basically have to use an ImageReader as the destination of your EGL rendering.

Comment: Thanks Eddy, I think `ImageWriter` would be synchronous, but it turned out that the HardwareBuffer APIs are for some reason kinda slow.

Comment: hey - I am using ImageWriter + MediaRecorder right now, and for some reason I cannot pass images through to MediaRecorder's surface. Do you maybe have any idea why? created a separate post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152531